# Haskell type inference with GADTs and typeclass constraints on type variables

Tags: haskell, type-inference, gadt

I defined a custom GADT where the type constructor has a type class constraint on the type variable, like this:

```hs
data MyGadt x where
  Sample :: Show a => a -> MyGadt a
```

Now, if I define the following two functions:

```hs
foo (Sample a) = show a

bar a = Sample a
```

GHC infers types for them that are a bit irritating to me.
`foo :: MyGadt x -> [Char]` doesn't mention the `Show` constraint for `x`, while `bar :: Show a => a -> MyGadt a` does require the constraint to be mentioned explicitly.

I was assuming that I don't have to mention the constraint because it is declared in the GADT definition.
The only thing I can think of being part of the reason is the position of the GADT in the function. I'm not super deep into that but as far as I understand it, `MyGadt` is in positive position in `foo` and in negative position in `bar`.

When do I have to mention the type class constraints explicitly, and when does GHC figure it out itself based on the constraint on the GADTs type constructor?

Comment: Constraints must be provided by the context on construction, and are instead added to the context on pattern matching. I don't understand the source of your confusion. Try pretending that constraints are just another argument to the constructor e.g. `Sample :: ShowDict a -> a -> MyGadt a`: you have to pass the extra argument on construction, and you get that value back on pattern matching. Constraints work in exactly the same way.

Comment: `bar :: a -> MyGadt a` claims that you can construct `MyGadt T` regardless of `T`, even if `T` is not in `Show`, but that’s not true because `Sample` requires a `Show` instance. Whereas `bar :: Show a => a -> MyGadt a` explicitly specifies that `bar @T` requires `T` to be in `Show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *the whole point* of using a GADT that you want the constraint to show up in the signature of `bar`, instead of `foo`. If you *don't* want that, then you can use a plain old `newtype` instead:

```
newtype MyAdt = Sample a

foo :: Show a => MyAdt a -> String
foo (Sample a) = show a

bar :: a -> MyAdt a
bar = Sample
```

Having the constraint in *neither* `foo` nor `bar` clearly can't work, because then you would be able to e.g.

```
showFunction :: (Integer -> Integer) -> String
showFunction = foo . bar
```

Comment: My source of confusion is that I have to add it explicitly on bar. Why is it "derived" from the fact that the type variable is used in the GADT which puts a constraint on it? I was naively thinking that the constraint on the GADT saves me from writing it in functions where I use the GADT

Comment: It does save you from writing it in functions where you use the GADT's values. That's why you don't need to mention it in `foo`. But you can't fulfill constraints out of thin air, so if you _generate_ a value using that constrained constructor, that's where you need to have the constraint in your context.

Comment: @l7r7 I find it clearest to think of constraints as "method dictionaries".  I.e. when you see `Show a => ...` think of it as `(a -> String) -> ...` -- it's just another parameter, which is the `show` method.  Then all these little corner cases make sense.  The GADT contains the dictionary as a field, so `bar` needs to be passed such a dictionary to construct the GADT.  The dictionary is present within the GADT when destructing it, so it does not need to be passed as a parameter.

Comment: I think I got it now. So with the analogy of the method dictionary in mind, the Constraint is only needed if I definitely have to access the dictionary, right?

Comment: @l7r7 if you definitely have access to the dictionary, that's exactly when it is _not_ needed! The constraint is needed if you use something that requires the typeclass, but the dictionary is not in scope yet. It could be in scope from a sufficient instance (e.g. you never need to mention `Num Int`), or from the signature of an encapsulating function, or from a GADT pattern already matched.